# "invalid 'times' value" error in stack function

Tags: r, stack, rasterstack

I would like to stack multiple GeoTIFF file. My code looks like this:

```
var1 <- list.files(path="D:/#This is the access path", pattern=".tif$", full.names=TRUE)

var1

var2 <- stack(var1)
```

and here is the error:

> Error in rep.int(factor(names(x), unique(names(x))), lengths(x)) :
> invalid 'times' value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not done `library(raster)` to get the `stack` function from there. There's a `stack` function in base R which is erroring.

I can replicate your error from a fresh R session:

```
> var1 = list.files(path=".", pattern=".tif$",full.names=TRUE)
> var1[1:3]
[1] "./BRIUOUCOEF.tif" "./COOEJCKLGF.tif" "./CYEVPONYZY.tif"
> stack(var1)
Error in rep.int(factor(names(x), unique(names(x))), lengths(x)) : 
  invalid 'times' value
```

Then if I use the `raster` package it doesn't error like that anymore (but I get a different error because my rasters are all over the place):

```
> library(raster)
Loading required package: sp
> stack(var1)
Error in compareRaster(rasters) : different extent
>
```